# Android Studio Can't attach source and documentation for Java JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Android Studio has no way to add source code and documentation for the java JDK.  I tried going to project External Libraries, right mouse click on JDK, there are no library properties.  The "Attach Source" does not pop up when I jump to the source.  It ends up showing de-compiled source code. Is this controlled by the gradle files somehow?

Does anybody know how to fix this?